# Validating URL using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a URL with just a scheme and domain name (something like `http://www.domainname.com`). I am using this regex:

```
/^(http|https):\/\/[\w.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}/
```

When I type `http://www.ab`, up to 6 characters it returns true, after that length it return false. How can I tackle this situation?

Comment: There is a whole set of regexes of varying complexity and correctness presented at https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex (the first google result when typing "url regex")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex like this : `https?:\/\/www\..*?\.(com|uk|in)` (you have to specify what all you want to match at the end.

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dD3yF4/1)

Comment: wow... this would be very nice . But i have to specify each domain name extensions.... that is a worst task !!!

Comment: @sudeep - is the domain `http://www.abc.xysdasaa` valid?. You will have to ensure that this isn't accepted right?

Comment: @TheLostMind That could be valid in the future. So I think that validation might only be syntactic.

Comment: @PacoAbato - in that case he might as well use `https?:\/\/www\..*?\\.*`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/xR0oV9/1

Let me correct a bit your pattern, just for information.

Instead of `(http|https)` much shorter would be `(https?)` because `http` part will be in both cases, and `s` is optional.

Instead of this: `[A-Za-z]` you can just use lower case letters: `[a-z]` and add `i` modifier to the end of your pattern (after last slash `/`) which would mean case insensitive match.

Answer (score 0):

This one from [diegoperini](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) is maybe a little bit longer but therefore it's nearly perfect (atleast in my eyes).

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

If you want to use it in C# you have to slightly change it. I've done this already some time ago.

```
^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$
```